# Live Agent Transferred Chat Button Id

Tags: visualforce, liveagent

Is it possible to get the chat buttonId on Custom Chat window visualforce page in which chat got transferred? I have some logic on buttonId and if chat got transferred to different button the i need to rerun some logic.

Thanks
Chaithra